# How can I load a Papervision/Flex application (SWF) as a material on a Papervision plane?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, papervision3d

I am trying to  build a portfolio application similar to the used by [Whitevoid](http://www.whitevoid.com/portfolio/). I am using Flex 4 and Papervision3D 2. I have everything working except for one issue. When I try to load an external SWF as a material on one of the planes, I can see any native Flex or Flash components in their correct positions, but the papervision objects are not being rendered properly. It looks like the viewport is not being set in the nested swf. I have posted my code for loading the swf below.

```
private function loadMovie(path:String=""):void
{
    loader = new Loader();
    request = new URLRequest(path);

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, addMaterial);

    loader.load(request);
}

private function addMaterial(e:Event):void
{
    movie = new MovieClip();
    movie.addChild(e.target.content);
    var width:Number = 0;
    var height:Number = 0;
    width = loader.contentLoaderInfo.width;
    height = loader.contentLoaderInfo.height;

    //calculate the aspect ratio of the swf
    var matAR:Number = width/height;

    if (matAR > aspectRatio)
    {
        plane.scaleY = aspectRatio / matAR;
    }
    else if (matAR < aspectRatio)
    {
        plane.scaleX = matAR / aspectRatio;
    }

    var mat:MovieMaterial = new MovieMaterial(movie, false, true, false, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));

    mat.interactive = true;
    mat.smooth = true;
    plane.material = mat;
}
```

Below I have posted two pictures. The first is a shot of the application running by itself. The second is the application as a MovieMaterial on a Plane. You can see how the button created as a spark object in the mxml stays in the correct position, but papervision sphere (which is rotating) is in the wrong location. Is there something I am missing here?

[image: Sphere]
[image: Plane]

Answer (score 0):

Man. I haven't seen that site in a while. Still one of the cooler PV projects...

What do you mean by:

> I cannot properly see the scene rendered in Papervision

You say you can see the components in their appropriate positions, as in: you have a plane with what looks like the intended file loading up? But I'm guessing that you can't interact with it.

As far as I know, and I've spent a reasonable amount of time trying to make something similar work, the MovieMaterial (which I assume you're using) draws a Bitmap of whatever contents exist in your MovieClip, and if you set it to animated=true, then it will render out a series of bitmaps - equating animation. What it's not doing, is displaying an actual MovieClip (or SWF) on the plane. So you may see your components, but this is how:

MovieMaterial.as line 137

```
// ______________________________________________________________________ CREATE BITMAP

        /**
        * 
        * @param    asset
        * @return
        */
        protected function createBitmapFromSprite( asset:DisplayObject ):BitmapData
        {
            // Set the new movie reference
            movie = asset;

            // initialize the bitmap since it's new
            initBitmap( movie );

            // Draw
            drawBitmap();

            // Call super.createBitmap to centralize the bitmap specific code.
            // Here only MovieClip specific code, all bitmap code (maxUVs, AUTO_MIP_MAP, correctBitmap) in BitmapMaterial.
            bitmap = super.createBitmap( bitmap );

            return bitmap;
        }
```

Note in the WhiteVoid you never actually interact with a movie until it "lands" = he's very likely swapping in a Movie on top of the bitmap textured plane.

The part that you are interacting with is probably another plane that holds the "button" that simply becomes visible on mouseover.

I think PV1.0 had access to real swfs as a material but this changed in 2.0. Sadly. Hopefully Molehill will.

cheers

Comment: I added more info for you, as well an example. I can interact with the button just fine and I can see the sphere spinning. It is just not scaling or repositioning the sphere correctly.

Comment: what version of PV are you using? Interesting you got that to work, I've had the exact same setup with no joy... So anyway - content is showing up, but is mis-aligned. So check out the Viewport.autoScaleToStage prop. Its set to false by default, so try "true". Alternately, do you have the stageScaleMode / stageAlign set in the swf? Align to TOP_LEFT may solve this for you as well.

Comment: I'm using the latest release version, 2.1.932. I've tried the scaling both ways but it never seems to work. I just left the scalemode and align as their default values. I would like to be able to take a swf created by another developer/group and use it regardless of those settings. My planes are very small, only a couple hundred pixels in both directions, so I think it might just be hitting a minimum. I was kind of hoping that the embedded swf would use the plane as it's stage instead of the browser and the embedded scene would get scaled by the plane.

Comment: Hmmm.. I doubt there is some kind of minimum. what It certainly looks like is happening - instead of using the plane as its stage, the loaded swf is using the parent stage. Does the sphere move with the scale of the parent container? tough to say. Some weird interaction of stageScaleModes and nested stages... You might try scaling the loaded movie down to match the size of the plane your applying it to instead of the reverse.

Comment: The sphere is staying that same position and scales with the plane even when the moves and when I resize the whole window. If you scale the movie before adding it to the material it simply stretches it back out to fit the plane. I might be wrong but it looks like applying a material always fills the entire plane.

Comment: Yep. The the bitmap/movie *should* stretch to fit the dimensions of the plane. So - you scaled the parent movie? what about the child movie (the loaded swf)? What I meant was keep the parent MovieClip at 100% and modify child (tho that might be what you did). Whatever the case, the issue seems to be: the PV scene is retaining its native resolution instead of scaling to match its container (the plane) - thats why I was thinking autoStageScaleMode. Sorry, not being much of a help here... PV tends to be kinda finicky. I'm probably out of guesses without the project in my hands to tinker with...